# How to get size of the Object in java

Tags: java, object, size

I used below code but i am getting the null pointer exception on using getObjectSize method

```
 import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

    public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
        private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

        public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
            instrumentation = inst;
        }

        public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
            return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
        }
    }

public class C {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(new C()));
    }
}
```

Comment: `instrumentation` is null?

Comment: Yes i am geting instrumentation as null

Comment: @SandeepKumar Gee I wonder what could be wrong then...

Comment: instrumentation value is initialized in premain() and since it is not called, instrumentation remains as null

Answer (score 1):

It seems you newer call premain method so you never initialize the instrumentation field.

Comment: what parameters should i pass while calling premain() method

Comment: Well the parameters of the premain method are a string and an Instrumentation objects so you need to provide them.Since Instrumentation is an interface you will need something that implements it. For example you could use InstrumentationImpl.

Comment: i tried using InstrumentationImpl for creasting the object, but i am not able to create object since the constructor is private.

Comment: I also tried for creating my custom implementation of Instrumentation but i am getting the object size as null

Comment: Ah ok sorry i didn't realize it. 
Read more about instrumentation in the docs it explains how you can get an instance 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html